# Benchmarks of scripting languages doing the same task?

Tags: php, python, ruby, perl, benchmarking

Does anyone know where I could find reviews or reports on tasks that people implemented in two or more scripting languages to see which was more suited to a specific job? I want to know which languages are best suited to which types of operation so that I can make the most of them.

"Types of operation" could be sockets, the file system, logic evaluation, regex, or drawing.

I'm mostly interested in Python, PHP, Perl, and Ruby.

Comment: Isn't this highly platform dependent as well?

Comment: As far as I know, these languages run on almost every platform. Naturally, the tester should be smart enough to compare two languages on the same platform.

Comment: Let's throw Lua in there too...

Comment: @Andrew Grimm - Maybe "more suited for a certain job?" is both vague and subjective? What would it mean to say PHP was more suited to regex than Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the programming language shootout:
http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/
Although it may not measure enough of the things you're looking for.

However, benchmarks almost certainly won't tell you anything useful about high level ideas of the sort you listed. For those things, the performance (as in speed of execution) has almost nothing to do with what language the code is written in (at least for the set of languages you listed, all of which have quite similar execution models), and almost everything to do with how the code is structured.

If you want to be able to choose one of the languages you listed (for a particular task) based on something relevant, the questions you should be asking are:

- What restrictions are there given the platform you want to run on? All of the languages you listed have large runtime systems -- interpreters -- which means they may have heavy deployment costs if you want to use them on systems on which they are not already installed. Having said that, Python at least has 'py2exe' and 'py2app' which can be used to make deployable executables of your application for Windows or Mac -- there may well be something similar for the other languages you listed.
- What relevant functionality is provided in the standard library for the language?
  (in this case, all the listed languages have very large, useful standard libraries).
- What relevant functionality is available in external libraries that you could use?
- How comfortable are you using the language?

Finally, if execution speed really is very important in your application, and if you find that you can't achieve the speed you need even with an appropriate choice of architecture in your chosen language, then you can identify the bottleneck and re-implement that in a compiled language, providing an interface back to the scripting language so it can be integrated into the application. All of the languages you listed support such native-code extensions.

Comment: Yes, doing some small part of the application in c++, c# or even c, seems like a good idea. And you are totally right about the dangers of choosing a language based on benchmarks instead of high-level application design choices. For example, basing design off query times to a database - when you should be placing memcached in between your app and data.

Comment: +1: "benchmarks almost certainly won't tell you anything useful".  Stop there.  Benchmarks are largely a waste of time because they **must** involve some kind of apples to oranges comparison.  Benchmarks among things so dissimilar as programming languages -- are of no value at all.

Comment: It'd be nice if it had info on ruby 1.9.2 versus 1.9.1.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm - Isn't that something to be done by the Ruby 1.9 team? Meanwhile you could just diff the data files - https://alioth.debian.org/scm/viewvc.php/shootout/website/websites/u32/data/ndata.csv?root=shootout&r1=1.491&r2=1.492

Comment: @S.Lott >> Benchmarks are largely a waste of time because they must involve some kind of apples to oranges comparison. << When our choice is between apples and oranges, a comparison between apples and oranges is of value.

Comment: @igouy: "When our choice is between apples and oranges" a benchmark is just misleading numbers.  Avoid throwing numbers at a problem until you have something with few enough degrees of freedom that measurements actually mean something.  Benchmarks between languages have so many assumptions, caveats and alternatives that they're   useless.

Comment: @S.Lott >> Benchmarks between languages have so many assumptions, caveats and alternatives that they're useless. << When our choice is between languages our choice is based on many assumptions, caveats and alternatives - and we still have to make a choice.

Comment: @igouy: I don't disagree.  You still have to make a choice.  But.  Don't waste your time on hypothetical, random benchmarks.  It's impossible to reduce the degrees of freedom to a statistically meaningful level.  People still use slower languages (like Java) because they think Java has advantages over faster languages like C.  Benchmarks just clutter a difficult decision with random numbers.

Comment: @S.Lott >> Don't waste your time on hypothetical, random benchmarks. << It would have been so much more interesting if you'd have written - Don't waste your time on specific benchmarks that match your usage. Perhaps people "still use slower languages (like Java) because" they can see it isn't slow like interpreted Java, just slower like JIT Java http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/compare.php?lang=java&lang2=javaxint

Answer (score 3):

I would look at [the programming tasks on Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Tasks).

You should be able to find idiomatic code for the languages you're interested in, and then benchmark under whatever usage conditions you expect. This frees you from having to write the tests yourself, and you often see interesting approaches for the different languages.

Comment: Wow, that Rosetta Code database is really useful! Perfect for seeing multiple solutions to (mostly simple) problems in different languages.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do would be to create your own benchmarks for the specific tasks you are interested in. Pick languages that you like working in and then write benchmarks for the system you will be using and the task you will be performing. If you are very concerned about speed I would also recommend looking at the individual operations and how to optimize them in each of the languages (examples: argument order, memory usage...)

Comment: That would be nice if I had the time - and to a degree I will have to do this. However, I'm hoping that there are some that have gone before me that might have useful information.